# how do I use JOIN, WHERE AND GROUP BY in the same query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've started using SQL (postgresql to be specific) and I'm wondering why my query that uses a JOIN WHERE and GROUP BY doesn't work

I have two tables and its the classic one-to-many relationship. for example I have one table called `users` the other is `products`. A user has many products.

```sh
# users columns
id
user_name
yearly_budget
```

```sh
# products columns
id
user_id
price
product_name
purchased_at(datetime)
```

a user has yearly budget that. the query I want to get all the users (or just one) and group the day by year and sum up all the prices of products the user has spent and then I want to compare that against their yearly budget to see if they went over it for that year.

this is the SQL query I have so far.

```sql
SELECT
    users.id,
    yearly_budget,
    sum(price) as total_price,
    date_part('year', purchased_at)  as year_purchased
FROM users 
JOIN products on products.user_id = users.id 
WHERE yearly_budget < total_price
GROUP BY users.id, year_purchased;
```

but I keep getting the error  `column "total_price" does not exist` I really don't understand what that means. If I remove the last WHERE statement I can clearly see the total_price column.

Comment: add sample data and expected result

Comment: WHERE is a row level condition, HAVING is GROUP condition. Since total_price is the result for the GROUP, you must use HAVING

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I come from the Oracle Side of SQL.
There you have a HAVING clause which works just like a WHERE clause only that it enables you to access results of a group by.
It should look something like:

```
SELECT
    users.id,
    yearly_budget,
    sum(price) as total_price,
    date_part('year', purchased_at)  as year_purchased
FROM users 
JOIN products on products.user_id = users.id 
GROUP BY users.id, year_purchased
HAVING yearly_budget < sum(price);
```

Comment: let me try this. does the HAVING have to come after the GROUP BY? does the order of the statements in SQL matter?

Comment: Is it possible to do this without the having statement

Comment: The order of the statements definetly matters. Even the order of the Tables in the Join may affect the performance, not so much the result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting tripped by the order of which those statements are actually executed, the total_price is an alias that in fact does not exist when the where part of the query is executed, you need to write `sum(price)`instead.

Comment: that doesn't work either. `sum(price)` is the same as `total_prices` isn't it. but either way it doesn't work. `aggreagate functions are not allowed in WHERE`

Answer (score 0):

Not a beauty, however you may try some kind of subselect. Additionally, I think, you missed out on the Yearly_Budget in the "Group By"

```
Select * from (
SELECT
    users.id,
    yearly_budget,
    sum(price) as total_price,
    date_part('year', purchased_at)  as year_purchased
FROM users 
JOIN products on products.user_id = users.id 
GROUP BY users.id, yearly_budget, year_purchased) a
where a.yearly_budget < a.total_price;
```